# How do you force a figure redraw ipython notebook inline?

Tags: ipython, pandas

I am using pandas and ipython notebook inline. I drew a figure with pandas dataframe

```
figure()
subplot = df['likes'].hist()
subplot.set_title("Likes")
display(fig)
draw()
```

I am trying to add a title to the histogram for example and I'd like to redraw it, but ipython notebook does not redraw.

Does anyone have a suggestion? In ipython when I use draw() it redraws and adds a title. I want to format my pandas plots.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that ipython notebook closes the figure after I execute the cell's code. To format the axes I have to execute all the code in a single cell.

Comment: There's a setting to control it: `%config InlineBackend.close_figures=False`